# Stemming + stop word filtering in Lucene 4.0+

Tags: lucene, stemming

I used to use `SnowBallAnalyzer` to combine custom stop word filtering with basic stemming, but it has been deprecated. For e.g. in index config, I could easily specify:

```
IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_32,
                new SnowballAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_32, "name", stopSet));
```

where `stopSet` is my custom list of stopwords.

How do I now create a single analyzer that would enable me filter stop words and do basic English stemming?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [EnglishAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/en/EnglishAnalyzer.html):

```
new EnglishAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_32, stopSet)
```

I'm a little confused on how your listed code does anything particularly useful, if you aren't passing a valid stemmer name into the SnowballAnalyzer constructor.  Seems like it should throw an exception right around here:

```
 Class<?> stemClass = Class.forName("org.tartarus.snowball.ext." + name + "Stemmer");
```

Being that there is no stemmer called: "`org.tartarus.snowball.ext.nameStemmer`".

Comment: Thanks. It's not very clear from the documentation that `EnglishAnalyzer` also does stemming.